# Geom_jitter colour based on values

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

Is there a way to color the jitter points on a boxplot based on a numeric value, so for example:

```
ggplot(data, aes(y = y_var, x = x_var)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 2, aes(color = ifelse(y_var < 5, "red", "black)))
```

I've added this reproducible example that doesn't quite work (the colors on the plot don't correspond to the jitter call):

```
a <- rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 1)
b <- as.factor(sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))
test_data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
test_data$b <- as.factor(test_data$b)

ggplot(test_data, aes(y = a, x = b)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_jitter(aes(color = ifelse(a < 5, "red", "black")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not quite, see my reproducible example above.

Comment: You can use `scale_color_identity` to set the colors as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804570/2461552).  Or move `color` outside `aes()`: `color=ifelse(test_data$a<5,"red","black")` if things are simple.

Comment: Ah yes, i'll follow the scale_color_identity, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Listing names of colors in your geom as you did doesn't tell the color scale what colors to use—it just breaks values into categories. The strings `"red"` or `"black"` don't necessarily have any meaning there. If you want to assign colors inside a geom, give the color names or hex codes you're using, then add `scale_color_identity` so there's an indication that `"red"` actually means "make this have a red color," etc.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(test_data, aes(y = a, x = b)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = ifelse(a < 5, "red", "black"))) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Better yet (and more scaleable and maintainable) is a separation of concerns: let geoms handle creating geometries and mapping onto scales, and let scales handle setting what scales look like. You can use `a < 5` as the variable (kind of a proxy variable, since it isn't in your data frame) which will take on true or false values. Then use a color scale, such as `scale_color_manual`, to set colors based on true or false values.

```r
ggplot(test_data, aes(y = a, x = b)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = a < 5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "red", "FALSE" = "black"))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).