# ggplot color is not automatically coloring based on group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create to lines on a graph by group 'candidate'[image: Dataset]

My code is
`ggplot(grouped_covid, aes(x=newDate, y = positiveIncrease, group=candidate, color = candidate)) + geom_line()`

When I set `color = candidate`, I get `Error: Unknown colour name: Clinton, Hillary`. My understanding is that it should just automatically set the color based on the grouping under candidate but it seems think I am trying to define the colors.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `group=candidate`?

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: It seems from your screenshot that your candidate column is of the type `<I<chr>>`, probably added as column with `grouped_covid$candidate <- I(some_variable)`. Try converting it to a plain character and running your plotting code again. Also @WhipStreak23's latest suggestion to use the `$`-operator inside `aes()` is generally not a good practise.

Comment: I'm new to R, can you elaborate on what the type <I<chr>> is and how I should convert it to plain character?

Comment: @teunbrand I am aware of using the `$` inside `aes()` is bad practice, however, it has worked for me occasionally when the more conventional way fails.

Comment: @Mike49 You can convert it to the plain character by using the [toString](https://rdrr.io/r/base/toString.html) or as.character function.

Comment: @teunbrand and mike49 - actually I did not know you could use `I()` instead of scale...identity. kind of fun. :)

Comment: @Tjebo me neither, but it appears to be a feature as there exists a `scale_type.AsIs` S3 method for automatically determining the scale, and it returns the "identity" scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@teunbrand was spot on.
Interesting. You may have somehow more or less voluntarily used `I()`, which lets R interpret an object "as is". See also `?I`

Here how to convert back to plain character:

You can do that either temporarily in the call to ggplot itself, or more permanently, by assignment (which I think you want to do).

**update**
in the comments, user teunbrand pointed to the S3 Method `scale_type.AsIs`, which is why using an "asIs" object works just like using `scale...identity`

```r
## this is to reproduce your data structure
iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species <- I(as.character(iris2$Species))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris2, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point()
#> Error: Unknown colour name: setosa

#convert withing ggplot
ggplot(iris2, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = as.character(Species))) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
## convert by assignment
iris2$Species <- as.character(iris2$Species)

ggplot(iris2, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>