ggplot assigns incorrect colors to lines
Minimal example (simple classification):
library(ggplot2)
N  <- 10
mu <- 10
ones <-  rep(1, 3*N)

x1 <- c(rnorm(N) - mu, rnorm(N), rnorm(N) + mu)
x2 <- c(rnorm(N) - mu, rnorm(N), rnorm(N) + mu)
z1 <- c(rep(1, N), rep(0, N), rep(0, N)) * mu
z2 <- c(rep(0, N), rep(1, N), rep(0, N)) * mu
z3 <- c(rep(0, N), rep(0, N), rep(1, N)) * mu 

df <- data.frame(Intercept = ones, 
                 x1 = x1, 
                 x2 = x2, 
                 z1 = z1, 
                 z2 = z2, 
                 z3 = z3)

coef1 <- lm(z1 ~ x1 + x2, df)$coef
coef2 <- lm(z2 ~ x1 + x2, df)$coef
coef3 <- lm(z3 ~ x1 + x2, df)$coef
coeff <- cbind(coef1, coef2, coef3)

X = as.matrix(df[, c("Intercept", "x1", "x2")])
Y = as.matrix(df[, c("z1", "z2", "z3")])

lines <- as.data.frame(X %*% coeff)
colnames(lines) <- c("Left", "Middle", "Right")
df <- cbind(df, lines)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x1, y = x2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = Left, color = "red")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Middle, color = "blue")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Right, color = "green"))

The lines are colored incorrecly. The first line (Left) should be downward sloping and should be red. The second line (Middle) should be roughly flat and blue. The third line (Right) should be upward sloping and green.
But the downward sloping line is colored blue, the flat line is red and the upward sloping line is colored green. The legend has the labels and colors mixed up as well: the short red dash is labeled blue, and the short blue dash is labeled red. The green dash is labeled correctly.
The coefficients look fine, as do the fitted values, but the plot is clearly incorrect. What is the source of my error? I'm on R 4.4.1.
Sincerely and with many thankks in advance.
Thomas Philips

If you want ggplot() to interpret the color names as colors you have to use scale_color_identity, e.g. + scale_color_identity(guide = "legend", labels = c("Middle", "Right", "Left")) to additionally add a legend and correct labels. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934522/ggplot-wrong-color-assignment. Note: A better approach would be to reshape your data to long though.

Also have a look at Add legend to ggplot2 line plot to set the colors for a line plot.

Thanks, I was unaware of scale_color_identity. Your second reference is even better and more comprehensive. I was experimenting with ggplot and deliberately avoided melting / reshaping the data.
